# How to loop div like angular js using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have use this following technique to replace sting in html.

```
var str = "Some html values";
var res = str.replace("{company}","Microsoft");
```

But i want to loop div like angular js by using pure JavaScript like shown below

```
{foreach value in values} <div class="test">{value}</div> {/foreach}
```

if anyone knows please let me know

Comment: That's possible to do using innerHTML, but you should be using a for loop and jQuery's .append() for this.

Comment: Why is that tag `angularjs` if you don't want to use it?

Comment: But i didnt use jquery or javascript any plugins.. i want to implement in pure javascript eg if "var values" has array value means i want to execute in foreach loop just like angular js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way in vanilla JS :

```js
 var values = ["Microsoft", "Apple", "Amazon"];
 var node = document.getElementById( "myDiv" );
 var res="";
 for (id in values){
  res+="<p>"+values[id]+"</p>";
 }
 node.innerHTML=res;
```

```html
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

Comment: I have tried this but if it contains multiple div means like

<div class="1">
     <div class="2">
     </div>
</div>
if i want to loop "class 2" means i have to declare that class and div in script. I don't want to do that. Any other possibilities without declaring class or divs in script ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

```js
 var values = '';
 var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e']; 
 var meanings = ['apple','banana','choclate','dominoes pizza','eggs']
 var value = document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML;
 for (var i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++) {
  values += value.replace("{value}",alphabet[i]).replace("{meanings}",meanings[i]);
 }
 document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = values;
```

```html
<div id="test2" class="test">
 <div id="test1" class="test">
  <div class="test">
   {value} for {meanings}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```